# Apache/php redirect loop

Tags: php, apache, redirect

Here is the situation in the smallest explanation I can give.

From php, I do a redirect with the following function

```
function redirect($loc)
{
    session_write_close();
    header("Location: $loc");
    exit();
}
```

For example, `redirect('http://www.google.com/');`

The problem is that when I attempt to do `redirect('https://local.application.com')` the browser gets a header that says `Location: https://local-apps.application.com`. `https://local-apps.application.com` is the uri that the original request comes through.

I've used xdebug to step through the php code right up to `header('Location: $loc');` call and I can verify 100% that `$loc == 'https://local.application.com'` because xdebug tells me so. However, for SOME reason, the browser gets `Location: https://local-apps.application.com`. This causes an infinite loop as `https://local-apps.application.com` once again redirects to `https://local.application.com`.

What is maybe going on?!

The extremely weird part is that putting the SAME EXACT code in our qa environment yields the expected behavior and NO INIFINITE loop is caused. In qa the urls are qa-apps.application.com and qa.application.com.

I don't know if my local Apache is doing this. I doubt it's php's fault because xdebug shows me for certain that the $loc variable is set to the right uri and I'm doing an `exit` right after.

I've also tried using Charles web proxy to act as a man in the middle to look at traffic but it also shows `Location: https://local-apps.application.com` instead of the expected `Location: https://local.application.com`.

Is there an Apache setting that would alter outgoing headers? What should I do?

**EDIT 1**

I altered my Apache access log to print out the Location header in the response and it is the correct value. So apache isn't doing anything weird here.

**EDIT 2**

I removed all entries from my /etc/hosts file. I then installed [dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html) and set it up as the primary DNS server for my computer. I tested this by doing `dig @127.0.0.1 local.application.com` and then `dig @127.0.0.1 www.google.com` to make sure I had set it up correctly.

I added `address=/local.application.com/127.0.0.1` and `address=/local-apps.application.com/127.0.0.1` to the dnsmasq config and restarted dnsmasq. I even restarted my computer after setting it up as a daemon that starts on reboot.

I get the same weird behavior on my local machine. My webbrowser goes into an infinite loop.

### More info if you are curious

I'm putting together an oauth2 implementation in my workplace.

The authorize point exists on my local machine at local-apps.application.com/authorize (local-apps) because that's where mobile apps will access it. In production it would be apps.application.com/authorize. (Sorry, I can't control the subdomains being used).

Depending on the client_id in the initial oauth2 auhorize request I will first redirect to a client appropriate domain. From `local-apps.application.com/authorize` I'll go to `local.client-1.com/authorize` and then from there I would redirect to `local.client-1.com/login` if the oauth2 credentials are validated successfully.. Why the extra redirect? 1. A limitation in the way our templating system works and the fact that it depends on the domain to load the proper html. 2. The sessions for php don't transfer across domains so I have to start the php session on the right domain. I can't change it. I just have to deal with it. Please don't make suggestions related to this url scheme thingy. I just want to know why php redirects to one url and the browser get a different url in the header.

Comment: Have you cleared your cache? Also you can configure Apache to log redirects if it doesn't already. Might want to look into that.

Comment: I have cleared my cache on my browser. And I used an incognito window. I also used Opera, Firefox, and Safari and my local still exhibits the same behavior.

Comment: I don't know if I can do that with Apache. I'll have to look into enabling deeper logging.

Comment: This seems to be an issue with Chrome. I tried Safari and I had no redirect loop or other issues. I'm going to test altering my cache headers. Maybe Chrome is doing something iffy here.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, you have a same ip addresses in /etc/hosts file or you can check your Apache virtual host file to make sure the correct path. 
Note: Apache configuration files location and directory structure depends on the linux distro.

Comment: yes i have the same ip address in my host file listed for the two addresses.

Comment: Can you please specify which linux are you using? Is it ubuntu? If it is ubuntu then you can check your file under /etc/apache2/sites-available/local.application.com. It's http handle is working fine as per your posted code. You need to look into its https handle in same folder. you can look into this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-with-a-free-signed-ssl-certificate-on-a-vps  and read only "Activating SSL Certificate.  I hope this is helpful.

Comment: I'm using mac os x yosemite.